# Failover mechanisum for WCF services serving enterprise application

Tags: wcf, failover

We have set of WCF services running on single computer which collectively serves an WPF application which could be on same machine or on remote machine (within same network only). We need failover mechanisum so whenver any of the service crashes or hangs - we want to restart the service and initialize it by calling appropriate method.

Since we are not aware of what is the industry standard for implementing failover for WCF service - we have implemented like this way. We start main WCF service hosted in console app along with one more secondary WCF service which constantly checks health of main WCF service by calling exposed method on given endpoint. If main WCF service fails, it takes role of main WCF service and launches another secondary WCF service.

The above approach is working fine but only problem we have seen is memory since we launch services in pair and every host requires 10MB of memory.

Can anyone help me what is the industry practice for implementing failover for this kind of scenario?